# Need to write an sql statement that returns a value in decode statement when two or more criteria match results it in one row only

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write an sql statement that returns a value in decode statement when two or more criteria match results it in one row only.

```
Select DECODE(resource_type,('1' AND '2'), 'NO', 'YES') Resource_present 
from Resource where resource_id = 'XYZ'
```

Is it possible any how.?
Please help....

Comment: How can `resource_type` be both '1' and '2' ? did you mean `OR` ?

Comment: you could use the 'CASE .WHEN. THEN .ELSE.END syntax in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` instead of `decode`:

```
Select CASE WHEN resource_type IN ('1' , '2') THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END Resource_present 
from Resource where resource_id = 'XYZ'
```

Another option is to use more arguments in the decode:

```
Select DECODE(resource_type,'1', 'NO', '2', 'NO', 'YES') Resource_present 
from Resource where resource_id = 'XYZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about writing your own function and implementing the logic inside it and calling that function with your SQL-Statement?
I would be easier to read and you could implement, if needed in future, further logic.

Parameter would be the field ressource_type and return of that function would be a varchar.

(i would have written that as comment, if i would be allowed to...)